# how to update GCP Buckets ACLs using terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am unable to update bucket ACLs using terraform. I am getting below mentioned error:-

Error retrieving current ACLs: googleapi: Error 403: @appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to , forbidden

But if I tried to add ACLs using GCP CLI it works.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, it looks like the default App Engine service account PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com is missing storage.buckets.get permission.

After you added ACLs using GCP CLI, do you try to re-enable API for your application?

These links [Cloud IAM permissions for the Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-console) and [Granting roles to service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts) for you consideration.

Comment: I am the owner of that group that means I have all the permissions if the issue is coming why it is not coming with GCP CLI but with terraform only

Comment: @Mukul When you use the gCloudSDK and you authenticate it, you use your own credentials, that as you mentioned, you are the Project Owner. When you attempt to make the change with terraform, a [Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) is used instead, and this has not set properly the permissions, that is the difference. Could you please try what William said and share the results?